# Add a point to a plot with a mouse event

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to click on my graph and add a point to it. I am using event handling, but the append command is not working.

My Code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


class LineBuilder:
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.line = line
        self.xs = line.get_xdata()
        self.ys = line.get_ydata()
        self.cid = line.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.click)


    def click(self, event):
        if event.inaxes != self.line.axes:
            return
        self.xs.append(event.xdata)
        self.ys.append(event.ydata)
        self.line.set_data(self.xs, self.ys)
        self.line.figure.canvas.draw()


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('click to add a point')
line, = ax.plot([], [], 'o')  # empty point
linebuilder = LineBuilder(line)

plt.show()
```

My Error:

```
numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append
```

Comment: Just as the error says, numpy arrays have no `append` method. You may use a normal python `list` instead or the [`numpy.append`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) function.

Comment: The list worked! Thanks!